# css dropdown not showing in iMac Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Total dropdown has been made on **css** and on scroll navigation position fixed made by a little bit vanilla javascript.

**For Scroll Positions**

```
/**
 * Sticky JavaScript Navigations
 * For Home Page Only
 */


window.onscroll = function () {
    navSticky()
};

const mghFixedNav = document.getElementsByClassName("mgh-main-nav-area")[0];

// const sticky = llnav.offsetTop;
function navSticky() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {

        mghFixedNav.style.top = "50px";
        mghFixedNav.style.width = "100%";
        mghFixedNav.style.left = "0";
        mghFixedNav.style.right = "0";
    } else {
        mghFixedNav.style.top = "75px";
        mghFixedNav.style.width = "95%";
        mghFixedNav.style.left = "2.5%";
        mghFixedNav.style.right = "2.5%";
    }
}
```

**Firefox** and **Chrome** browser work perfectly but the **Safari** browser in iMac not showing the navbar and dropdown.

Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/momin-ctg/pen/zXMRQw)

Anybody can help me ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the following CSS code and it will start working on Safari:

```
//header top

header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/sasiddiqui/pen/bJQxKa) by which you can directly verify that.

Comment: Note: FF and Chrome are correct, fixed positioned element have no parents for what the renderer is aware.

Comment: @Momin Dropdown is working for me in Safari. Here is the screenshot: http://www.screencast.com/t/IQewoNNW

Answer (score 0):

You should not really use window.onscroll for creating such effects, there are better, more performant ways to do this, [the intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

With this you can check how much of an element is visible without listening to the scroll event and without recalculating it permanently, the browser will do this for you.

First you define the observer:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '10px',
  threshold: 0.2
} 

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

in your case your target would be something like this:

```
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("mgh-main-nav-area")[0];
observer.observe(target);
```

I can't write the code for your problem from the top of my head, I'm sorry about that. But I hope I could at least point you in the right direction on which tool you should use.

Here is one example I found for [toggling a sticky-class](https://usefulangle.com/post/108/javascript-detecting-element-gets-fixed-in-css-position-sticky) for a fixed nav :)

Comment: My problem was cross browser compatibility ! Safari browser did not show the navbar also css dropdown

Comment: Just wanted to point you in a more modern and performant solution. I know that for this you would have to rewrite your code, if you don't chose to use it, fine for me. Maybe in your next project you will use this performant way to implemt such a thing :)